# Is it possible to count line shapes in a PDF page using iText 7

Tags: itext

How to get the count of all line shapes created by PdfCanvas.stroke() method?

```
let pdfDictionary = pdfDocument.GetPage(1).GetPdfObject()
let foundObjects = pdfDictionary.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.???)
```

What 'PdfName' property should be used as a parameter? 'PdfName.Line' does not work. 
Maybe I am looking wrong way.

EDIT:

Some PDF pages have one line and some three lines and it is the only one attribute for filtering documents. I need to filter documents by the count of these lines.
Maybe I have to find another way for achieving this goal.

By the way, lines are black and have fixed position and size. Maybe I should check the spot color at certain positions? If it is possible...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you're looking the wrong way, the `Stroke` method results in an **S** instruction in the content stream the `PdfCanvas` in question is working on. That content stream might be anything from a page content stream to a pattern content stream, from an annotation appearance stream to a font type 3 glyph definition, ... Thus, you should describe in more detail what you want to count.

Comment: *"Some PDF pages have one line and some three lines"* - have you made sure that the pages with one line don't actually also have three lines but two of them are hidden? (E.g. by something covering them, or using transparency, or drawing white on white?) And are you sure those lines are drawn by stroking a line path and not by filling a thin rectangle path or even by drawing a bitmap image showing those lines?